# Is this a safe way to release resources in Java?

Tags: java

Usually when code needs some resource that needs to be released I see it done like this:

```
InputStream in = null;
try{
    in = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
    doSomethingWithStream(in);
}finally{
    if(in != null){
        in.close();
    }
}
```

What I don't like is that you have to initialize the variable to null and after that set it to another value and in the finally block check if the resource was initialized by checking if it is null. If it is not null, it needs to be released. I know I'm nitpicking, but I feel like this could be done cleaner.

What I would like to do is this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
try{
    doSomethingWithStream(in);
}finally{
    in.close();
}
```

To my eyes this looks almost as safe as the previous one. If resource initialization fails and it throws an exception, there's nothing to be done(since I didn't get the resource) so it doesn't have to be inside the try block. The only thing I'm worried is if there is some way(I'm not Java certified) that an exception or error can be thrown between operations?

Even simpler example:

```
Inputstream in = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
in.close();
```

Is there any way the stream would be left open that a try-finally block would prevent?

**Edit:**

Maybe I should have left out the last example because it confuses everyone. This is not supposed to be a beginner level question. I know what try-finally does and I know that it is not safe if there was doSomethingWithStream in the middle in the last example. That is why it is not there. I accepted Eyals answer because it was precisely what I was looking for. There is a way to cause an exception between two operations, which would make the middle example unsafe(using Thread.stop), but since it is made using deprecated call and can mess you up no matter what you do so I feel safe using the middle example.

Comment: By the way, if you are using Apache Commons, you can `IOUtils.closeQuietly(in)`.  This utility function checks for `null` and suppresses `IOException` as you are probably not interested in exceptions on closing anyway.

Comment: @doublep: thanks for the tip. Seems like there is a lot of other useful stuff there too.

Comment: For clarification, in the last example the doSomethingWithStream is left out intentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, an exception can occur between the 2 calls in the last code sample,and leave the resource open. If the thread is stopped violently by another thread using the Thread.stop() or Thread.stop(Throwable) immediately after the stream construction, the thread will throw an exception (ThreadDeath in the first case), and the resources will not be disposed of.

But this is exactly why these methods are deprecated...

Comment: Do you think this is a serious enough issue that I shouldn't use the way I'm releasing the stream?

Comment: True, but adding `try`-`finally` will not help.

Comment: Why wouldn't it help?
I mean if the last example would be guarded like the first example, wouldn't it be safe even from ThreadDeath error?

Comment: @palto: Imagine if the exception is thrown after the resource is acquired but before the assignment to the variable...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That would be a bug in the resource acquisition code, not mine. Not my problem :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Now that I think about it for awhile, you are right. ThreadDeath could break up the resource acquisition code without it having bugs. Well, maybe I shoudn't worry about ThreadDeath then

Comment: @palto: It doesn't even have to interrupt the resource acquisition code itself - if it happens after the method/constructor has returned,  but before the assignment occurs, there are problems...

Answer (score 2):

The middle sample is safe - the last one isn't.

A try-finally block means that the stream is closed even if `doSomethingWithStream` throws an exception. Yes, you could catch all exceptions and then close the stream that way - but it's much simpler to let the exception bubble up to the caller, but close the stream on the way via the finally block.

Comment: The last one is safe as it is, but I guess intention was to put `doSomethingWithStream(in)` in between.  Then it wouldn't be safe, of course.

Comment: Why is the last one not safe? (I was too slow, doublep answered alread)

Comment: The intention was not to put the doSomethingWithStream(in) between the calls in the last example. I guess the question is more like "Can something go wrong between these two operations".

Comment: Whilst the last one is safe, it is not so safe when you consider maintenance (such as making the code do something).

Comment: @Jon: Why isn't the last code sample safe? I don't see how the resource can be left open. The only problem with this code as I see it, is that it isn't useful in any way - the stream is never used.

Comment: (Technically something could go wrong, but there is usually little you can do about that. (To avoid this problem `java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged` uses the Execute Around idiom, implemented by searching through the stack every time a check is made.))

Comment: Suppose an exception stops the `close` from being run. There's no guarantee how long it will be before the `FileInputStream` is garbage-collected (if ever), and until then the underlying file handle will be open. The total number of file handles that may be open at once in a process is usually fairly small (a few thousand is a common limit) so a leak of FDs, i.e., a leak of `FileInputStream` objects, is serious.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: But how can there be an exception? In the last example exception can be thrown in getting the stream, but then you won't get a stream to close. If there is an exception in the close-method then there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: @palto: if you're genuinely doing nothing with the stream then I guess it's safe... but pretty pointless. How often do you open a stream and then just close it? Personally I'd still use a finally block in that case, so that it's easier to modify the code later without introducing a bug.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I have never written code like that and I probably never will. I'm just trying to find out if anything can go wrong there. The last example is purely theoretical.

Comment: @palto: In that literal code, it will work. It's also a waste of effort (beyond testing whether the file can really be opened for reading; there are cases where that's useful and less costly schemes don't work as well, but I doubt the wilder reaches of filesystem semantics are what you're looking for here). **However**, in the case where there's something real happening between open and close (which is what everyone was assuming you were asking about) that's when the last form is a problem.

Comment: BTW, in case you *are* interested, the value in opening a file for reading comes because it's much more reliable as a way of determining if a file is really readable. The classic probes (e.g., examining permissions) don't work well in the presence of things like ACLs, and the implementation of the `access()` syscall has historically been spotty (especially with networked filesystems). That's to say nothing of the race condition between checking a file for readability and reading it (but if you cared about that, you wouldn't be closing the handle again immediately…)

Comment: @Donal: Yes, I've seen it very occasionally for exactly that reason. But I don't think it's something you'd need to write often :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). It has a @Cleanup annotation which is settable on local variables which will [auto-generate code at compilation time](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) to clean up the resource.

```
 import lombok.Cleanup;
 import java.io.*;

 public class CleanupExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     @Cleanup InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
     @Cleanup OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
     byte[] b = new byte[10000];
     while (true) {
       int r = in.read(b);
       if (r == -1) break;
       out.write(b, 0, r);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but seems like it is pretty much married to Eclipse and I use Netbeans.

Comment: I'm not happy about the way it mishandles Eclipse either, to be honest. It uses bytecode rewriting and changes methods in-memory for which the API could change at any time.